# RMI Service run similar to sockets

Tags: java, sockets, networking, parallel-processing, rmi

So if I have a socket server, I can accept each socket and pass it to a executory

```
while(true){
            Socket conn = socketServ.accept();
            Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        server.executor(conn);
                    } catch(IOException e){

                    }
                }
            };
            exec1.execute(task);
        }
```

Doing this allows my server to run on my threads and does not block the same thread. Because I also have reference to that socket... called "conn" I can successfully return messages as well.

Now I have an RMI interface, which basically lets me call methods back and forth.

for example if I had this method:

```
public MusicServerResponseImpl CreatePlayerlist(String Name, UserObjectImpl uo) throws RemoteException {
        MusicServerResponseImpl res = new MusicServerResponseImpl();



        return res;
    }
```

Which returns a serializable object. My concern is when this message gets called, I think it is going to get called in the main thread of the server, and thus will block that thread and slow down parallelism.

What I think is the solution is to have every single RMI method also create a task for an executor.. to speed up the execution of everything...this issue I am seeing however is unlike the socket where I have an object to send information back to, I am unsure how I would return a response from the RMI method, without somehow having to block the thread.

Does that make sense? Basically I am asking how I can execute in parallel with RMI methods while still being able to return results!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> Does that make sense?

No. Concurrent calls are natively supported.

See [this documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html) and look for the property named `maxConnectionThreads`.

You could also have tested your assumptions by, for example, printing the current thread name in your server code, and trying to execute concurrent calls and see what happens.

Comment: Okay.. didn't realize that. I guess that makes my life a lot easier. SO your saying natively itll be running multi thread